Crate returning from the method
I'm trying to build an asynchronous JSON-RPC server in Rust using the jsonrpsee crate from Parity. I'm registering an asynchronous method using the following function:
pub fn register_async_method<R, Fun, Fut>(
    &mut self,
    method_name: &'static str,
    callback: Fun,
) -> Result<&mut MethodCallback, RegisterMethodError>
where
    R: IntoResponse + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = R> + Send,
    Fun: Fn(Params<'static>, Arc<Context>, Extensions) -> Fut + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,

Here’s an example of how I’m currently registering a method:
use jsonrpsee_core::server::RpcModule;
let mut module = RpcModule::new(());
module.register_async_method("say_hello", |_params, _ctx, _| async { "lo" }).unwrap();

What I'm trying to do: I want the registered method to return either a successful result or an error, depending on some condition. I’m unsure how to modify the callback function to return a Result<R, Error> or a custom error type when a certain condition is met. Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly return a Result from the method and handle errors?
Example scenario: I want to return a custom error if a certain condition is met (for example, invalid parameters), otherwise return a success message.

Callback can return any future that "resolves" to any type implementing IntoResponse + 'static. You did not provide information about types and traits in your question, but I would guess that this trait allows you to customize response. It probably already is implemented for Result<T, E> where T: IntoResponse, E: IntoResponse.
